# Is encrypting a CRC with the plaintext ok?

Tags: encryption, hmac

We're using encrypt-then-mac for authenticated encryption, and recently added a CRC32 to the plaintext. Are there any security problems with using a non-authenticated hash mechanism (for example, CRC32) for error detection (ie ensuring the message wasn't mangled, and it was decrypted with the correct key)?

So the format would be (`||` is concatenation):

```
encrypt(msg||crc32(msg))||mac(ciphertext)
```

Does this result in a reduction in security, similar to using encrypt-and-mac or mac-then-encrypt?

Comment: Tip: you open with a controversial statement that you're only backing up with Wikipedia. If you want an objective answer to your actual question, you might want to edit out the flame-war-bait.

Comment: The MAC over the ciphertext should be more than enough to check for error detection.  I don't think the CRC over the plaintext gains you anything, but I also don't think it will hurt anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wouldn't do this and don't understand what problem you are trying to solve (unless this is a purely academic question).

Encrypt-then-MAC where we define `ciphertext=encrypt(K_enc, msg)` and sending `ciphertext||MAC(K_mac, ciphertext)` will detect any transmission errors or malicious tampering by someone who doesn't know the secret MAC key `K_mac` with overwhelming probability; e.g., if you used an 80-bit MAC the probability of tampering a message and getting the MAC to pass is 1 in 2^80 ~ 8 x 10^-25 which is negligible.  E.g., if someone generated a **billion** forged messages every second, it would take about 3.2 million years before they had an 8% chance of a single successful forgery (or about 26 million years before they have a 50% chance of a single successful forgery).

So the 80+ bit MAC provides strong security against successful forgeries or transmission errors by itself.

Meanwhile, the 32-bit non-cryptographic non-keyed CRC32 hash does not provide any additional integrity check against someone deliberately tampering with a plaintext message they can guess, at least with stream ciphers (or block ciphers acting like a stream cipher like CTR or the one-time-pad) where XORing a change to the ciphertext modifies the same bits in the plaintext.  E.g., as CRC32's do not involve any secrets, they can guess the original message `m`, calculate it's CRC32, take their intended tampered message `m'` and calculate it's CRC32, and then modify the ciphertext in transit to `c' = c XOR (m || CRC32(m)) XOR (m' || CRC32(m'))`.  Granted, the keyed MAC provided by authenticated encryption does prevent this attack.  However, if you had a bad implementation that said provided information (either through an error message or change in timing) of a difference between the MAC failing and the CRC32 failing or when the MAC fails and the CRC32 passes, you would weaken the security of your system (and attackers could exploit this).

The only protection that the CRC32 could protect against is accidental memory corruption in your computer between calculating the CRC32 of the plaintext message and encrypting said message though the chance of that happening is also negligibly small.

In summary, if this is implemented poorly (e.g., the attacker can figure out that the CRC failed/passed even when the MAC failed), this can leak information.  If this is implemented perfectly, it would not provide any additional security as the keyed MAC is the part that would thwart a dedicated tamperer.

Answer (score 0):

## This will not harm the encryption, but it doesn't really add anything either.

What you've described is just encryption. You've only changed what the payload is by making it a little bit larger. This is just as safe.

However a mac also contains a check in it that if it was mangled in transmission in either part(encrypted message or the mac) it wouldn't confirm on the other end. You really gain nothing from this and it actively makes usability worse since now they also have to remove the last 32 characters from the payload.

Comment: The CRC is a fixed size, so we're assuming the last 32 bits of the plaintext is the CRC. This does result in a non-zero probability that we get a hash collision with mangled data and it passes the check, but that's a general problem with using hash functions.

Comment: Then this should be just as safe. You're encrypting the message and the hash now in a single go in your payload, but that's not changing the algorithm for having at all. It's just as secure as long as you take the other room ended syeps